# Não foi possivel conectar: Nenhuma conexão pôde ser feita porque a máquina de destino as recusou ativamente

Tags: php, mysql, conexão

Estou tentando conectar ao meu banco de dados. Trata-se do easyphp webserver 14.1.

[image: MYSQL]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o codigo php para conexão.

```
<?php 

$HOST = '10.40.0.185:3388';
$USER= '*****'; // Aqui informei o usuário do meu banco
$PASS= '*****'; // Aqui informaei a senha do usuário para acesso ao banco
$BANCO = 'gclient_embratel';

$conexao = mysql_connect($HOST,$USER,$PASS) or die('Não foi possivel conectar: '.mysql_error());

$selecao = mysql_select_db($BANCO);?>
```

Segue a mensagem de erro: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Podem ser várias possibilidades: 1 - O servidor de banco de dados não esta iniciada na máquina (mais provável), 2 - Um firewall pode estar bloqueando o acesso a porta do MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

**Resposta:**

Como você esta utilizando o banco de dados na mesma máquina da aplicação a configuração de conexão com o banco de dados pode ser alterada para:

```
<?php 

    $HOST = 'localhost:3388';
    $USER= '*****';
    $PASS= '*****';
    $BANCO = 'gclient_embratel';

    $conexao = mysql_connect($HOST,$USER,$PASS) or die('Não foi possivel conectar: '.mysql_error());

    $selecao = mysql_select_db($BANCO);?

?>
```

No lugar do IP da sua máquina externa definido na variável `$HOST` coloquei o valor `localhost`, mas poderia ser utilizado também `127.0.0.1`.

Quanto a conexão recusada pode ocorrer por vários fatores, sendo os principais:

1. O serviço do banco de dados MySQL não foi iniciado e não esta rodando na porta 3388. Se você utiliza Linux pode fazer o comando `fuser 3388/tcp` para verificar se há um processo utilizando essa porta.
2. Há alguma restrição no firewall da sua máquina para a porta 3388.
3. Você esta utilizando uma máquina da `Amazon Web Services` para a sua aplicação? É necessário liberar a porta nas configurações de segurança da sua instância.

Colocando o valor `localhost` na variável `$HOST` provavelmente as opções `2` e `3` são descartadas porque a porta 3388 da máquina local será acessada sem precisar de acesso externo.